# Parsing lengthy string in Java

Tags: java

I am getting the following string in my java app from a client.

```
[["UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"],["UILabel","User name","15","75","80","80"],["UITextField","Jonathan","15","75","80","80"]]ˇ˛END
```

I am expecting to parse this and take out separately as 3 strings as like below:

```
"UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"
"UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"
"UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"
```

I have tried like below,

```
    // resultStr = [["UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"],["UILabel","User name","15","75","80","80"],["UITextField","Jonathan","15","75","80","80"]]ˇ˛END
    if ( resultStr.length()>0 && resultStr!=null ) {

        for (int i=0; i<resultStr.length(); i++) {
            int startInd = resultStr.indexOf('[');
            int endInd = resultStr.indexOf(']');
            if ( startInd>=0 && endInd>0 ) {
                String resStr =  resultStr.substring(startInd , endInd);
                if ( resStr!=null )
                    System.out.println("Applet resStr: " + resStr);
            }
            else
                System.out.println("Applet startindex, endindex failed");
        }
    }
```

But, this is not working, this is not rightly parsing like what I expected. Could someone advise how to parse the string separately as I expected ?

Comment: Use a JSON parser?  There are plenty listed for Java on [json.org](http://json.org).

Comment: whats this at the end of the string `ˇ˛END` ?

Comment: I will have to remove this too -> ˇ˛END  in program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split this string using `String.split()` method:

```
String[] t = myString.substring(2, s.length()-7).split("\\],\\[");
```

So your code will look like this:

```
//resultStr = [["UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"],["UILabel","User name","15","75","80","80"],["UITextField","Jonathan","15","75","80","80"]]ˇ˛END
if ( resultStr.length()>7 && resultStr!=null ) {

    String[] resStrings = resultStr.substring(2, resultStr.length()-7).split("\\],\\[");    
    for (String resString: resStrings) {
        System.out.println("Applet resStr: " + resStr);
    }
}
```

As a result, you should have following output:

```
Applet resStr: "UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"
Applet resStr: "UILabel","User name","15","75","80","80"
Applet resStr: "UITextField","Jonathan","15","75","80","80"
```

Comment: Applet resStr: "UIButton","Submit","15","30","80","80"
Applet resStr: "UILabel","User name","15","75","80","80"
Applet resStr: "UITextField","Jonathan","15","75","80","80"]]ˇ˛END

Comment: Can I remove ]]ˇ˛END  at the end?

Comment: In my answer, it is already removed. This is what `substring(2, s.length()-7)` is for.

Comment: Do you mean like this -> String[] t = resultStr.substring(2, resultStr.length()-7).split("\\],\\[");

Comment: It is not removing ]]ˇ˛END . I'll check again.

Comment: Maybe you 've got something more at the end of string? Try `substring(2, s.length()-12)`

Comment: Ok..Could you also give brief explain about how it is fixed perfectly in this line of code -> String[] resStrings = resultStr.substring(2, resultStr.length()-12).split("\\],\\[");

Answer (score 0):

Try with Pattern and Matcher using *Lazy* way and  [*Lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=\[).*?(?=\])
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL7xU7/3)

OR [*possessive*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) quantifier

```
(?<=\[)[^]]*+(?=\])
```

[online demo](http://regex101.com/r/qL7xU7/4)

Sample code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])").matcher(strring);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really help, the output is separated by commas too.